# correctness of "and the smallest last" vs "and the smallest, last"

Tags: commas, orthography, writing-style

Which is correct? If both are correct, is one more correct than the other?

> The largest pixie should be eaten first, and the smallest last.

> The largest pixie should be eaten first, and the smallest, last.

Comment: I've fixed the tags. This is not about grammar or grammaticality, but merely about commas, which are matters of orthography not of grammar. Style guides are often in disagreement about what commas go where and when. That means it is difficult if not impossible to csay that what one style book recommends is "correct" and what another style book recommends is "incorrect". These are not really words that can apply here.

Comment: More correct? Slightly pregnant.